# simplification of trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

I search a simplification for

$$ \arcsin\biggl( \frac{1}{\sqrt  2} \frac{x}{\sqrt  {(x-1)^2 +1}}\biggr)$$

any idea ? I tried composition, derivation and setting $x$ as a sine, cosine or a tangent in vain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us substitute  $x = 1 + \tan \theta $. We then get: $$E = \arcsin \left (\frac1 {\sqrt 2} \frac {1+\tan \theta}{\sqrt {\sec^2 \theta}} \right) $$ $$=\arcsin \left (\frac {1}{\sqrt 2} (\cos \theta + \sin \theta) \right) $$ $$=\arcsin \left (\sin \theta \cos \frac {\pi}{4} + \cos \theta \sin \frac {\pi}{4} \right) $$ $$=\arcsin \left (\sin (\theta + \frac {\pi}{4}) \right) $$ $$=\, ?$$

Comment: yeah you are certainly right but when I do this substitution, I don't have sqrt(sec^2) but sqrt(tan^2 + 1 ). I don't know the identities you use :/ could you be more specific ?

Comment: Note that as $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1 $, divide both sides by $\cos^2 x $ to get $\tan^2 x +1 = \sec^2 x $.

Comment: okay makes sens thx :)

Comment: No problem.....